# Angular2 view synchronized between two viewers

Tags: angular

I have a Angular2 application launched with npm start.

Someone knows why, when two viewers are connected at the same page, the view is synchronized?
By instance, I open two browser and I open the same application page. And when I scroll in the first page, it scroll too on the second one.

A idea ?

Comment: Do you use WebWorker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a feature of [`browser-sync`](https://browsersync.io/) that's used with `lite-server`. You can access it's options by visiting `http://localhost:3001/sync-options` by default.

Comment: Ahaha yes, it's that, I forgot this feature... thanks a lot !